# Understanding JQuery Filter Property

Tags: jquery, filter

I am trying to understand how the filter works and wrote a small html code as follows

```
<div id='btnContainer'>
    <input type="button" id='btnContinue' value='Continue'>
    </input>
    <input type="button" id='btnCancel' value='Cancel'>
    </input>
</div>
```

```
alert($('#btnContainer').filter('#btnContinue').length);
```

This results in a alert msg of 0 instead of the 1 I expect - jquery 1.44

Pointers please

Comment: `filter()` filters out the elements that do not match its argument. `id` selectors are mutually exclusive by definition, so this usage of `filter()` will always return an empty set. [Pointer](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: There are already good answers here explaining why it works as it does. I just wanted to point out that if you already have an id on an element (e.g., btnContinue), and you want to select it, then you should just use $('#btnContinue') to get it. Because no element can have the same id as another, the use of methods like .find() and .filter() are unnecessary when selecting elements by an id.

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

The matched elements for your selector `$('#btnContainer')` is the parent only, none of its children are included. If you want to filter the inputs, use:

```
alert($('#btnContainer').children().filter('#btnContinue').length);
```

Also, `input` elements are self-closing...

Answer (score 0):

The filter method reduces the matched set of elements by the selectors entered into the method.  You have selected one item, the #btnContainer and then have attempted to filter this selection for elements with the id #btnContinue.  In the set of elements you selected there are no elements with the id #btnContinue, there is only one element with the id #btnContainer, which is why you receive 0.

Proper use of the filter method would be to select multiple items, such as a bunch of divs with the same class name, and then to filter the divs you have selected using some other criteria.

This demo illustrates proper use of the filter method: http://jsfiddle.net/8AMYx/1/

Checkout the JQuery Documentation for other examples:
http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

`$('#btnContainer')` matches a single element - your first, top-level div.

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) reduces the set of matched elements to only those that match the new secondary selector -- in this case `#btnContinue`. Since the top-level div does not match the id-selector `#btnContinue`, the new matched set is empty.

If you want your initial selector to match the element and all of it's children, do:

```
var matchedSet = $('#btnContainer').find('*').andSelf();
```

Then you can do:

```
alert( matchedSet.filter('#btnContinue').length ); // == 1
```

[**Demo of corrected code**](http://jsfiddle.net/QEXAf/)

See the jQuery docs for [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's returning 0 items because there are no items with the id `btnContainer` and `btnContinue`

filter will reduce the result set to only items that match the `filter` selector.

You probably want this: `$('#btnContainer input').filter('#btnContinue').length`